# Map response to model object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am trying map response from GET call to my object which has properties 1:1 with JSON object. Here is my code:

thread model:

```
export class Thread {
  private source: Source;
  private target: Target;
  private messages: Message[];

  constructor(data) {
    this.source = data.source;
    this.target = data.target;
    this.messages = data.messages;
  }

  sum() {
    return 'Hello from Thread';
  }
}
```

thread service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ThreadService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  getAll(): Observable<Thread[]> {
    return this.http.get<Thread[]>('/api/thread').map(value => new Thread(value))
  }
}
```

getAll method in ThreadService gives me following error:

> src/app/service/thread.service.ts(13,5): error TS2322: Type
>   '`Observable<Thread>`' is not assignable to type '`Observable<Thread[]>`'.
>   Type '`Thread`' is not assignable to type '`Thread[]`'.
>       Property 'includes' is missing in type '`Thread`'.

Can you tell me what is the correct way to map response to model which allow me call custom methods in that model? I read something about interceptors to do that, but I can't find any example. Thanks for help.

Comment: You've said that the `get` will return a `Thread[]` and that the overall method will also return a `Thread[]` but the `Observable.map` passes the array into the `Thread` constructor and therefore returns only `Thread`, not `Thread[]`. Did you intend to use an `Array.map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Injectable()
export class ThreadService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  getAll(): Observable<Thread[]> {
    return this.http.get<Thread[]>('/api/thread').map(threads=> threads.map(thread => new Thread(thread)))
  }
}
```